# What is the most efficient way to cut/paste in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I find that I am cutting and pasting a LOT when I program. For example, method, variable and class names are things I regularly cut/paste. I do use "ctrl+space" after typing part of a word to autocomplete them or popup intellisense when there's duplicates found.

But just for straight copy/pasting do you guys have any good shortcuts/tricks/tips to use?

I already use these shortcuts as I program but I wonder if I am missing anything?

- ctrl+x (with nothing selected)
- ctrl+v (with nothing selected)
- ctrl+l (with nothing selected)
- ctrl+shift+arrowKeys

If I could copy/paste quicker I think I'd be able to write code quite a bit faster.

Comment: I don't get the mod-downs on this question. Typing and clipboard usage are things that we programmers spend entire days doing, and so this is a relevant question

Comment: me neither :( is this "too easy" a question or something? if so, give me a good answer and get some free points.

Comment: Are you sure you should be doing so much pasting of code? Perhaps you would have more success as a programmer if you changed your habits, for example more refactoring.

Comment: Jay - i figured someone would make a comment like this :) but i don't see how cut/paste is a bad thing. i'm trying to reduce my keystrokes and i do that by cut/paste as well as the other items i mentioned already. i don't really see how less cut/paste makes you a "better" programmer

Comment: @Jay Bazuzi:  he never said that he was not a successful developer.  I copy and paste all of the time.  Not logic, but names and whatever I need to, it doesn't mean that you are copying entire methods and classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install and learn [ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com/).

Answer (score 9):

In Visual Studio has multi-paste.
pressing Ctrl+Shift+V allows you to paste any of the 10 last things you cut/copied.

Answer (score 1):

I have more of a hardware solution.  On my [MS 4000 keyboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000A6PPOK) I have the back and forward buttons right under the space bar bound to copy and paste respectively.  This actually makes copying and pasting much easier than I thought it would when I first did it.

Answer (score 1):

I use [ClipX](http://www.bluemars.org/clipx/), which gives you system-wide multi-paste. You can paste any of the last [configurable number] of things in your clipboard. You can also save "favourite" items, which stick on the list forever.

Answer (score 0):

Shift + Page Up/Down to select everything below/above the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using ctrl+shift+arrow to select whole words/lines, then that can help a lot.